# On clicking hamburger icon does not open drawer layout in fragment in android studio

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout, hamburger-menu

I am using fragment and on clicking hamburger icon does not slide the navigation drawer from left. I used Drawerlayout as root view and then included the toolbar layout. It is showing the hamburger icon in toolbar.But on clicking does not open drawer layout.However simple sliding from left does open the navigation drawer.Here is my code:

```
mDrawer = mView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_view);
    nvDrawer = mView.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity = (AppCompatActivity)getActivity();
    appCompatActivity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    appCompatActivity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_artboard_1);
```

the on optionsitem selected function:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is for hamburger menu", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I want that when I click on hamburger icon,drawer layout comes.Please help me in doing so.

Comment: You should use `setNavigationItemSelectedListener`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Please elaborate ,I didn't get the exact idea how to implement this.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-use-navigationview-in-android